# Why does Photoshop say the f-stop is f1.6 in the summary but 1.4 in the details at the bottom?

Tags: photoshop, metadata, f-stop

Here is the picture; photo shot in `RAW`.
Why is it that at the bottom it says `f1.4`, but the summary on top says `f1.6`?
Plus, I am pretty sure flash fired too but again it is saying flash did not fire.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value (f/1.6) at the top is the aperture used when the picture was taken. The aperture value under *Camera Data (Exif)* (f/1.4) is the maximum aperture value to which the lens can be set.